# how to read from and write to a serial port (ttys0) from another pc via ethernet (eth0) on Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Well, there are two pc's connected via Wi-Fi and one of those (let's call it **A**) has a serial port printer (in **ttys0**) and a measure serial port device (in **ttys1**) connected too. So **B** needs to read some values from the mesure device connected on **A** and then write to the printer connected on **A** using a network connection.

Comment: Not a programming question -> Superuser

Comment: thanks but since this is part of a web app that I'm building is programming related right?

Comment: you are not seeking a solution to a programming problem. you're looking for a ready-made solution. how is this programming related? you're not asking how to "program" this are you?

Comment: Wow!, this is becoming really annoying so next time I won't ask anything here. Thanks to Nick and Adam for their answers.

Comment: coma, don't let ssg run you off.  Some people interpret StackOverflow differently than others.  I personally think your question was fine, so there's no reason to leave.

Comment: Thanks!!!
I really appreciate it.

Comment: coma I'm really sorry that I upset you. I didn't mean to be rude. But your argument "it's part of my web app" is not valid. For instance "How can I setup a Ubuntu server?" is a valid programming question in that sense. As @derobert recommended http://superuser.com/ seems to be the right place to go for such questions. You may not have recognized that it's a stackoverflow clone with the right audience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ser2net is a good solution for this

```
aptitude install ser2net
```

Then edit the config in /etc/ser2net.conf

You can then make a tcp connection to a defined port and be connected to the serial port on the remote computer - very useful.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if Ubuntu has anything built-in, but you could run a couple of daemons using netcat.  Of course, if you want it to be secure, you'd need to do a little more work.